# Is it possible navigate to new page when tap local notification? I am using Xamarin Forms and Plugin.LocalNotification

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using the plugin.LocalNotification and thinking about when tapping the notification and navigating to a new page, is it possible?
I am using Xamarin Forms. I know most of the developers move to MAUI, but I have to use XF.
Please help.

I want when tap the notification user can navigate to a new page
I tried to handle it from App.Xamal.cs
Will add code here later.
public partial class App
{

```
    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer)
        : base(initializer)
    {
    }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LocalNotificationCenter.Current.NotificationActionTapped += Current_NotificationActionTapped;

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IWebAuthenticator, WebAuthenticatorImplementation>();


        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainPage, MainPageViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewA, ViewAViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViewB, ViewBViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Notif, NotifViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Report, ReportViewModel>();


    }

    private async void Current_NotificationActionTapped(NotificationActionEventArgs e)
    {

        var notificationData = JObject.Parse(e.Request.ReturningData);
        int notificationId = notificationData.Value<int>("id");

        if (notificationId == 89)
        {
            
            await NavigationService.SelectTabAsync(nameof(Report));
        }
        else { LocalNotificationCenter.Current.Cancel(e.Request.NotificationId);

            
        }

    }
    

}
```

Comment: Yes.  Where is the code where you handle the notification?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of stuffing code into comments

Comment: Sorry, first time asking a question here.